# Android Setting->Display... What type of menu is that?

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build a menu similar to what you see when you go to Home->Menu->Settings->Display.

The menu there has sub menus, dialog popups, check boxes, and items that seem to launch other programs (like the calibration options). Anyway, what is that type of activity called? Is it just a listview? My app doesn't have anything to do with the android display settings. I just need that type of "advanced" controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a PreferenceActivity. Android controls the layout for you there.

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to search for something when you don't know what it is called.